# Flutter: info: 'await' applied to 'RemoteConfig', which is not a 'Future'

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-remote-config

I am getting an info message after upgrading my Firebase packages. The documentation wasn't helpful. The line below is triggering the info compiler alert.

```
RemoteConfig remoteConfig = await RemoteConfig.instance;
```

The info message is:

> info: 'await' applied to 'RemoteConfig', which is not a 'Future'. (await_only_futures at lib/splash.dart:72)

While this is just an 'info' message and doesn't prevent compilation, I want to make sure that I am not doing anything wrong. Please help.

Comment: As the error message says, `RemoteConfig.instance` is not a `Future`.  It makes no sense to `await` it.  Just remove the `await`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the FlutterFire documentation on [using Remote Config](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/remote-config/usage) shows, the call to `RemoteConfig.instance` is not asynchronous and is:

```
RemoteConfig remoteConfig = RemoteConfig.instance;
```

Where you *will* need to deal with asynchronous behavior is when [fetching the remote config](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/remote-config/usage#fetching-and-activating), which can be done with:

```
bool updated = await remoteConfig.fetchAndActivate();
if (updated) {
  // the config has been updated, new parameter values are available.
} else {
  // the config values were previously updated.
}
```

both snippets are from the linked documentation, so I recommend keeping that page handy.